# How can I completely remove the Windows 7 start menu user picture?

Tags: windows-7, start-menu

How can I remove this picture:

[image: Annoying user picture]

I've tried [this](http://www.door2windows.com/windows-7-start-menu-user-picture-remover-remove-windows-7-start-menu-user-picture-with-one-click/) without any luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

- Go to `C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\User Account Pictures`
- Rename `user.bmp` to something like `user.backup`
- Restart Windows 7

Comment: You should also rename `guest.bmp` if it exists to something else